# SQL INSERT INTO: comma as decimal

Tags: sql-server, internationalization, double, decimal

My problem is that my customer runs his SQL Server on a Windows box and the country settings are set to "Germany".

This means, a decimal point is NOT a point `.`, it's a comma `,`!

Inserting a double value to the database works like this

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myPrice) VALUES (16,5)
```

Works fine, so far.

The problem comes up if there is more than one value with decimal places in the statement like

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myPrice, myAmount) VALUES (16,5,10)
```

I get the error

> Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

Can I somehow "delimit" the values? Tried to add brackets around but this does not work.

Unfortunately I cannot change the language settings of the OS or the database because I am just writing some add-ons to an existing application.

Thank you!
ev

Comment: I find it hard to believe that first insert works.

Comment: You can't delimit them. Why not just pass the values in with decimal point instead of comma? No need to hack some other method together for this.

Comment: @DavidG He is saying that it should not be in decimal. its Germany, they use comma instead of decimal

Comment: @Shank Yes, but SQL Server will not take comma like this, it must be a decimal point.

Comment: Looking at the [German version of the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174335.aspx) sugguests that SQL Server still uses a comma to delimit fields.

Comment: Did you try this?: INSERT INTO myTable (myPrice,myAmount) VALUES (CAST(16,5 AS DECIMAL(5,2)),10)

Comment: @ErnstV, is this answer helpful to you? How you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must put the data in the format allowed by database. Even if you put data using comma... You may loose out numerical calculations.

If I get such situation.. I will check if comma is only required for visibility.. then I would display values in comma format while store them in decimal format.

This way data can be easily processed as numeric. But need to change it to and fro only for UI or display.

Based on this you may describe your situation in more detail if required.

EDIT: To verify my theory can you check if this insert statement has inserted 165 or 16.5 in the database.

```
  INSERT INTO myTable (myPrice) VALUES (16,5);
  select from mytable where myprice <17;
```

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please vote up. And share the resolution.